# Deleting multiple rows from MYSQL table based on column data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I have a table called user_favs like this :

```
 id | user_id | post_id
 ----------------------
 50 | 291     | 1027
 51 | 10      | 180
 52 | 771     | 1027
 53 | 92      | 133
 54 | 523     | 1027
```

How would I set up a database query in php to delete all rows that contain post_id 1027?

I know how to do it for single entries :

```
DELETE FROM user_favs WHERE post_id = 1027
```

But I don't know how to delete all rows that contain post_id 1027.

Is it something like :

```
DELETE * FROM user_favs WHERE post_id = 1027
```

I don't want to try it without knowing in case I mash the whole thing up ;)

Comment: If you're really unsure of what a statement or series of statements do, make a backup of your database with `mysqldump`, and try it out on the copy.

Answer (score 3):

this:

```
DELETE FROM user_favs WHERE post_id = 1027
```

will actually not delete only one row. it will delete all rows that matches the criteria `post_id=1027`

Comment: Ahh so that's exactly what I want! And now I read it back I feel very stupid as I can now see exactly why it would do that. I'll grab the dunce hat...

Comment: yeap. there's no 'delete one row' in sql, it works with criteria - everything that matches the criteria will be deleted, whether it's one row, zero or a million.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the first statement will work. Either way, I would recommend you to do a backup of your db before doing any change, even more, I would recommend you to do this type of trials in a vagrant box or in a database you dont care as the one you could create in your localhost.
instead of deleting, to check your code you could do: 
    SELECT * FROM user_favs WHERE post_id = 1027 
and see if it worked, if the results are the tuples you want to delete, whoala!